# Как добавлять в innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

Как делать так, чтобы innerHTML не очищал элемент, а что-то добавлял

```
document.getElementById('choise_area').innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто использовать предыдущее значение

```
<head>
<script>
    function w() {
        var z = document.getElementById('z');

        z.innerHTML += 'three...';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="w();">
    <div id="z">One, two, </div>
</body>
```

Получим

> One, two, three...