# Как правильно добавить значение к существующему тексту innerHTML

Tags: javascript, парсер, bitcoin

Есть такая функция:

```js
function RTCurrencies() {
  fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCUSDT')
    .then(a => a.json()
    .then(b => document.getElementById("btcusdt").innerHTML = (parseFloat(b.price).toFixed(2))))
}

setInterval(RTCurrencies, 5000);
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы спарсенное значение добавлялось в `innerHTML` к существующему тексту и в конце добавлялось USD, например, 1 BTC = спарсенноезначение USD.

При этом всём функция работает раз в 5 секунд (обновляет курс).

Comment: Здесь не фриланс

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавлять в innerHTML?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55291/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того чтобы менять значение `innerHTML` всего, можете менять только одну конкретную часть обернув его в `span`:

```js
function RTCurrencies() {
  fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCUSDT')
    .then(a => a.json()
    .then(b => document.getElementById("btcusdt").innerHTML = (parseFloat(b.price).toFixed(2))))
}

window.onload = RTCurrencies;

setInterval(RTCurrencies, 5000);
```

```html
<p> 1 BTC = <span id="btcusdt"></span> USD<p>
```

`window.onload = RTCurrencies` нужно чтобы в первый раз не ждать 5 секунд, появления значения